# How do I create an array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'm trying to create an array of pointers using my professors example in class. I can't seem to get it to work though.

```
char * ISBN[] = {
    "1-214-02031-3",
    "0-070-21604-5",
    "2-14-241242-4",
    "2-120-12311-x", 
    "0-534-95207-x",
    "2-034-00312-2",
    "1-013-10201-2",
    "2-142-1223",
    "3-001-0000a-4",
};
```

This is my professors example of declaring an array of pointers of type char. He says this is what we should do for the assignment. Sadly, I'm getting the error -
Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *" -

I've asked about this before and someone said that char * has been deprecated. But the professor says that this is the declaration that we should use for the assignment. How would I go about trying to figure out how to get this array working? What exactly is this declaration doing?

Comment: Make it "`const char *`" and you should be fine.

Comment: Add `const`. Your professor is likely teaching from a 20 year old syllabus. *String Literals* in C++ are `const char *` in C (and older C++) `char *` was allowed (even though the string literal was immutable). No longer.

Comment: As horrible as this sounds from a professional standpoint, Find out what compiler the instructor is using and get a copy of that to test your code against. You will have fewer surprises. For example if you make use of the `auto` keyword which changed behaviours about 10 years back or range-based `for` which didn't exist. Not to mention if you don fall victim to that blackest of scourges [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) you stand a better chance of the instructor's compiler interpreting it the same way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*String Literals in C++ are `const char *`*" - more accurately, they are `const char[N]` which can *decay* into `const char *`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, you are 100% correct. They are arrays that on access are converted to a pointer, subject to the normal exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char * ISBN[] = {
    "1-214-02031-3",
    "0-070-21604-5",
    "2-14-241242-4",
    "2-120-12311-x", 
    "0-534-95207-x",
    "2-034-00312-2",
    "1-013-10201-2",
    "2-142-1223",
    "3-001-0000a-4",
};
```

I guess I just needed to add `const` in front of `char *`. I still got much to learn. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Learning to program isn't a race, it's a journey. Enjoy it, and approach it the same way you would eat a whale -- one byte at a time...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin great. Now you're gonna have Greenpeace after you. Well, at least Rainbow Warriors are easier to spot than Ninja.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because you are trying to assign string literals to char pointer.In c++ string literals are const char pointer because as string literals are stored in read-only memory.Another reason is for optimisation for compilers(storing only one instance of a literal that is repeated many times in the source). So you get multiple pointers to the same memory, instead of each occupying a separate chunk of memory.